# Raspberry Pi 5 and Official 7" Touchscreen Blank with Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, touchscreen, pi-5

I got the Raspberry Pi 5 recently and got the latest version of Ubuntu running on it flawlessly (when hooked up to a monitor via the mini HDMI port).

I then got the official 7" touchscreen display and the display cable required for the Pi 5. I got it all hooked up aaaand... nothing. The Pi turns on and the display is black (as in, not turning on at all, not even the backlight).

All the connections look fine to me; I've double and triple checked that everything is in the right spot (e.g., the display cable has a weird twist in it, etc.). Here's some photos for reference:
[image: Photo of Pi 5 with Touchscreen]
[image: Photo of Pi 5 with Touchscreen]
[image: Photo of Pi 5 with Touchscreen]

I also tried this: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=318261 (i.e., commenting out the line and adding the auto detect line), with no luck.

On boot, I get the following (sometimes?):

```
[0.619126] sdhci-bremstb 1001100000.mmc: invalid resource (null)
[0.619149] schci-bremstb 1001100000.mmc: invalid resource (null)
[0.8376771] i2c_designware 100080000.12c: 12c_dw handle_tx abort: lost arbitration
[1.860824] i2c designuare 1f00080000.12c: controller timed out
[1.8608541] rpi_touchscreen_attiny 4-0045: Failed to read REG_ID reg: -5
Thu Jan 1 00:00:13 UTC 1970
writable: recovering journal
writable: Clearing orphaned inode 396716 (uid=123, gid=128, mode=0140775, size=0)
writable: clean, 192721/15528480 files, 3933588/62332667 blocks
[5.9888171] i2c_designware 1f00080000.12c: controller timed out
[5.988849] edt_ft5x06 4-0038: touchscreen probe failed
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: the flex cable looks like it is not plugged in all the way

Comment: the twist in the cable is suspicious

Comment: look at this https://www.adafruit.com/product/5821

Comment: It looks like the twisted flex cable is connected to a camera port rather than the display port.

Comment: @Dougie - aren't both of those ports on Pi-5 dual purpose - i.e. camera or display - *a pair of four-lane 1.5Gbps MIPI transceivers, tripling total bandwidth, and supporting any combination of up to two cameras or displays* - https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi-5.html

Comment: @Dougie the ports are the same. The difference is that you need different cables for display and camera.

Comment: To eliminate hardware and cable issues you may want to create a separate MicroSD card with RaspberryPi OS and try if that works. If that works and Ubuntu does not, then the problem is with Ubuntu. If neither works, it is probably a hardware problem.

Comment: @Milliways that was never true with 3B and earlier. I've not seen anything to refute that with 4B or 5B.

Comment: @Dougie it is well documented that the Pi5 uses different connections combining both functions; official resellers offer different cables.

Comment: OP here; I gave up trying to get it to work with Ubuntu. I installed the official Raspberry Pi OS alongside KDE and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

The error messages indicate some potential issues with the SD card interface, I2C controller, and touchscreen probe. Verify that the touchscreen display is compatible with the Raspberry Pi 5. Some displays may require specific configurations or drivers to work correctly.

You can also check the answer here: [edt_ft5x06 touchscreen probe failed with code -121](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/112383/edt-ft5x06-touchscreen-probe-failed-with-code-121)